# Java XML parse and write result in a missing end of line

Tags: java, xml, dom, output

Hello I want to parse an XML file and update some node and write it back to the file. When I do it there is lien break that has been removed.

To parse I use the `org.w3c.dom` library and to write back, I use `javax.xml.transform`.

Here is my input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?meta name="GENERATOR" content="XML::Smart/1.6.9 Perl/5.014002 [linux]" ?>
<inputs>
    <input id="1">value_to_be_edited</input>
</inputs>
```

Here is my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<?meta name="GENERATOR" content="XML::Smart/1.6.9 Perl/5.014002 [linux]" ?><inputs>
    <input id="1">new_value</input>
</inputs>
```

My problem is I don't want the line break to be removed (between the `<?meta ?>` and the `<inputs>`) and I don't want the `standalone="no"` to be added.

Here is my code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
... Here I edit the doc ...
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
// getIndentationSize() => this function send back the current indentation size of the file
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", String.valueOf(getIndentationSize()));
// isDeclarationPresent() => say if the <?xml ... ?> declaration was already there or not
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, (isDeclarationPresent()?"no":"yes"));
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Sorry for my English, I am French.
BR

Comment: This kind of question always is tricky. You should not want what you ask. The XML specification says what you actually get and what you want are identical XML documents (they do not _look_ the same, but they _mean_ the same). Thus, achieving what you want means fighting the XML implementations for making them do things they are not aware of. They have no way of achieving what you want, because they already are (normatively speaking). So you may find a way to make it do what you want... but you shouldn't have to. In other words : are your sure of what you expect ?

Comment: @GPI Thanks for the answer, I didn't know that they are the same from the XML specification. For my second question, about the `standalone="no"`, I try `transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");` but it didn't do anything, do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `OutputKeys.INDENT` property like shown below:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
```